Finding the general term of a given P-recursive sequence
I managed to prove that a certain sequence of rational numbers $(c_n)_n$ satisfies the following P-recursive equation:
$$3(n-1)(n+2)c_{n+2}=(3n^2-3n+2)c_{n+1}+6nc_n$$
with "initial conditions"
$$(c_2,c_3)=(1/2,1/3)$$
I proved that this sequence converges, but I'd like to give an explicit formula for $c_n$. Maple (or equivalent software) seems to be able to work this out, but I am not familiar with this technologies.

Question: is there a simple way to solve this equation? Do I have to learn computer algebra to get an explicit formula?
